# Where are the stickers located?

Tags: piczle-lines-dx

If you find the ten stickers you can unlock a set of free puzzles. The dev has confirmed you don't need to buy anything to be able to find all of the stickers but I am having trouble finding them all. Where are the stickers located? I know there are ten in total.

Answer (score 3):

Found them all ! I can only tell you the ones I remember sorry

1. Is in the shop on the pop corn machine
2. Trophy room 
   3.shop
3. Watching the whole cartoon for story mode
4. Click the symbol with the logo (top left) and it's on the web button)
5. For finishing info

And a couple in the puzzle packs

Answer (score 3):

These are the gig stickers I found in the iPhone version of Piczle Lines DX:

1. In the Tutorial, on the last page
2. On the main screen, on the top-left corner button
3. On the screen you see when you complete any puzzle, on the lower-left corner
4. On the Settings screen, on the lower-right corner
5. In Settings, in the Credits screen, on the web icon
6. In Story Mode, Chapter 1, main screen, on the side of the kitchen counter
7. In the Shop, on the side of the "Cheez" box
8. In the Trophy room, on the side of the sofa
9. In the Trophy room, in the Super Sleuth trophy screen (the the Super Sleuth trophy is in the lower-left corner of the Trophy room)
10. On the More Games screen, on the title